# I can not access http://localhost but http://127.0.0.1 works fine

Tags: windows, windows-vista, localhost

My http://localhost is not working. But the address http://127.0.0.1 is working fine. I have multiple webservers installed on my computer and it is the same problem with them all.

I think, but I don't know, that the problem started when I installed IIS, but I have inactivated IIS now.

I am using Windows Vista. How can I make http;://localhost working again?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "not working"?  Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check your hosts file - this is where host names are resolved in first place.
Normally, you should find this line there:

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

If not, add this line, save it and then test again, whether it works.

The hosts file can be found at:
`%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc`

You can edit this file with any text editor (e.g. notepad).

Comment: You beat me to it! ;) +1

Comment: Its name is hosts, not host.

Comment: Also.. sometimes things "trip out" and require a reboot after making this edit.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is Ubuntu 20.04 VM

I had this following line.

```
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

I commented that line and added the following line.

```
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

Basically removed

```
::1     localhost
```

It now works.

The final look of the hosts file is as follows.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       vagrant.vm      vagrant

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.2.1 w1 w1
```